# Implementation timecounter_init (clocksource.h) on kernel space gives Invalid ISA State Error

Tags: c, linux, time, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I'm implementing an embedded Linux OS on my stm32f429 with ARM Cortex-M4. In my code I need to implement the clocksource.h library for personal purpose for measuring elapsed time. The code on my system call is:

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/clocksource.h>


SYSCALL_DEFINE2(mycall, int*, arg1, char *, arg2) 
{
    struct timecounter *tc;
    struct cyclecounter *cc;
    long int value;

    local_irq_disable(); /*Disabling local interrupt*/


    spin_lock(&my_lock);

    timecounter_init(&tc,&cc,0);
    printk(KERN_INFO "PRINT\n");
    value = timecounter_read(&tc);

    local_irq_enable(); /*Enabling local interrupt*/


    return( value );
}
```

When I load my test app on my board and I run, the output gives me:

```
KERNEL: fault at 0xd00877e0 [pc=0xd00877e0, sp=0xd0019f58]
Escalated to Hard Fault
Invalid ISA state


Pid: 17, comm:                 test
CPU: 0    Not tainted  (2.6.33-arm1 #594)
pc : [<d00877e0>]    lr : [<d009ec19>]    psr: 6000000b
sp : d0019f58  ip : 08060501  fp : 00000000
Code dump at pc [d00877e0]:
d0094a69 d009122f d0087dc5 d00b2231 
r10: 01000000  r9 : d0018000  r8 : d0257ec4
r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00000000  r5 : ffffffff  r4 : d0019f84
r3 : d00877e0  r2 : 00000000  r1 : d0019f80  r0 : d0019f80
Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode UK11_26  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
Kernel panic - not syncing: 
Rebooting in 10 seconds..
```

How can I resolve? I must initialize cyclecounter cc? If yes, how?

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message? "Invalid ISA state" and "ISA ARM" mean you're trying to execute ARM, rather than Thumb, code, which the M-class architecture doesn't support. [As I pointed out the other day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094992/kernel-fault-on-implementation-of-cycle-counter-in-c#comment42696241_27094992), you're almost certainly not using the right compiler options. A dedicated Cortex-M toolchain, as opposed to a generic ARM one, would be useful as it would refuse to even generate these problems.

Comment: Hi @Notlikethat. You are very useful. If I ask a lot of questions is because I'm trying different implementation for cycle counter and timing. However thank you for explaination

Answer (score 0):

If you use SDK from Emcraft then yo need to check CFLAGS and LDFLAGS
like this

`CFLAGS="-Os -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -I /opt/linux-cortexm-1-12/A2F/root/usr/include"`

and

`LDFLAGS="-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -L/opt/linux-cortexm-1-12/A2F/root/usr/lib"`